# Catch function that initiates animation on element

Tags: javascript, animation, google-chrome-devtools

I need to grow my debugging skills. I have to find the peace of code that animates position of element. Animation begins after ajax, xhr requests are sutisfied. The property name "left"
[image]

If you can't help me without example, visit this http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_45344/404.html

So the question is not "what function...", but "how to find what function..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly enabled the `Break on Attributes modifications`, which will mean the debugger will break when your style changes, as per below:

[image: Sync Stack Trace]

You can see what function is called to trigger the attribute change. However, it is just the minified jQuery. With a source map configured, you would see things a little more clearly. However, this is still not your code. That is the problem.

Your code is triggered asynchronously, which can sometimes be a pain to debug. However, Chrome has a neat feature that allows you to [debug asynchronous code](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/). Enable as per below:

[image: Asynchronous Enabled]

Now when you try to debug your code, you can scroll down in the call stack and find your original calling code outside of the current execution context.

[image: Asynchronous Call Stack]